# Selenium python Getting some value

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYJkW.png)

I need the number value any way how to get them

Comment: Please provide a minimum amount of code along with explanation on what you have tried to solve the issue. An image is not enough for us to work on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

driver.find_elements_by_class_name('notranslate')[0].innerText

To fetch any DOM element object you can use functions given here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/element-methods-in-selenium-python/

Answer (score 0):

You need to download an HTML page. Than you need parse it.

For the first task I suggest [requests library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Installation

```
pip install requests
```

Docs have nice examples, I think you need simple GET HTTP request

```
r = requests.get('https://your.site/path')
data = r.text
```

Then you need parse HTML. I recommend [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Docs have examples, I think your code would like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
el = soup.select("Your CSS selector")
```

Here you need to find out right [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). You can try CSS selector like this `span.current`